# Should MPI_IRecv/MPI_ISend have the same `count`?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

Should a pair of `MPI_IRecv/MPI_ISend` get the same `count`?

```
 int MPI_Irecv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source,
           int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Request *request)
 ...
  count
    number of elements in receive buffer (integer)
```

The [documentation](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Irecv.html) seems to suggest it should not but I am confused by the wording and it is formulated a bit differently from [MPI_Recv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Recv.html). I am attaching an example which works as I am expecting if I pass different `count`.

**isend.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>  
#define send_cnt  1
#define recv_cnt 10    
#define SEND 0 /* who sends and who receives? */
#define RECV 1    
#define TAG 0
#define COMM MPI_COMM_WORLD  

MPI_Status  status;
MPI_Request request;

void send() {
  int dest = RECV;
  int buf[] = {42};
  MPI_Isend(buf, send_cnt, MPI_INT, dest, TAG, COMM, &request);
  MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
}

void recv() {
  int dest = SEND;
  int buf[123];
  MPI_Irecv(buf, recv_cnt, MPI_INT, dest, TAG, COMM, &request);
  MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
  printf("recv: %d\n", buf[0]);
}
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rank;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(COMM, &rank);    
  if (rank == SEND) send();
  else              recv();    
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Irecv` take as an argument the maximum amount of data elements that are allowed to be written into the buffer. This number does not necessarily have to be equal to the count passed to `MPI_Send` - it could be larger or smaller. When there is not enough space in the receive buffer to accommodate the message, MPI will signal a truncation error. When there is more space than the message size, only a part of the buffer will be written over. In the latter case one could use `MPI_Get_count` to examine the MPI status object returned by `MPI_Recv` / `MPI_Test*` / `MPI_Wait*`.

There is a legitimate case of the count passed to `MPI_(I)Recv` being smaller than the count passed to `MPI_Send` - different datatypes. For example, one can send 10 `MPI_INT`s and receive a single element of a contiguous datatype that consists of 10 `MPI_INT`s. In your case both the send and the receive operations use the same datatype, therefore the receive count must be at least as big as the send count.

By the way, your code is missing a call to wait/test the request created by `MPI_Isend`, which is erroneous.

Comment: You can also use `MPI_Send` to send messages to be received with `MPI_Irecv`.